# Save all subsequent view controller states in UINavigationViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a container `UIViewController` that hosts a single `UINavigationController`. The container view controller has a button that opens a new view controller by calling `present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`.

The `newViewController` has its own `UINavigationController` and also contains a button. That button can `present` another view controller that itself has a `UINavigationController` and another button and so on.

I want to keep that pattern going for as many iterations as possible and save the states of all of them. Is that possible? To close the current view controller I call `_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` but that erases all the data from the previous view controller as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked two questions

1) want to keep that pattern going for as many iterations as possible and save the states of all of them.

Ans. : you can not continuously presenting view on already presented view controller. for that first you need to dismiss previous presented view.

2) To close the current view controller I call

```
 _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

but that erases all the data from the previous view controller as well.

Ans. If you present any view controller then don't use popviewcontroller but use dismisViewController.

Comment: Hope you got the solution with this answer. Please upvote answer if yes.. :)